# Hyperbolic paraboloid

Tags: analytic-geometry

help me out with the following question.

Find the coordinates of the vertex and equation of the hyperbolic paraboloid $4x^2-y^2-z^2+2yz-8x-4y+8z-2=0$

Comment: The equation is $4x^2-y^2-z^2+2yz-8x-4y+8z-2=0$, probably.